# Custom taxonomy link opens under Posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, admin-menu

I have a custom taxonomy which I want to appear under a custom menu. And I achieved that by specifying the custom menu as the parent. Here's the result:

[image]

However, when I click on it, the CSV Tag Upload menu collapses, and the taxonomy opens itself under the Posts menu:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix it? I've been having this problem for a long time now, but it's becoming a problem now.

**EDIT:**
Code for registering taxonomy:

```
function csv_tags_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'CSV Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'CSV Tags' ),
        ); 

    register_taxonomy('csv_tags','post',array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'csv-tags' ),
        ));
}
add_action('init', 'csv_tags_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Please, show us the code you are using to register the custom taxonomy.

Comment: I edited the original post.

Comment: Note the second parameter of `register_taxonomy` function, you have registered the taxonomy for posts, that is why it appears under Posts menu.

Comment: I wish it were that easy :D the second parameter of register_taxonomy refers to the post type to which the taxonomy is tied. This taxonomy is tied to posts, but I don't really use it for posts, I use it for something else. I guess the only way to do this is to incorporate iframes or something.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is that easy, if you associate a taxonomy and a post type, they are associated, if you don't associate them, they are nost associated. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem even though my taxonomy was registered to Users. Found the answer at [Custom user taxonomies in WordPress by Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress) (see the comments for the post).

Add this to your code (replace YOUR_TAXONOMY with the proper name):

```
function fix_user_tax_page( $parent_file = '' ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == 'YOUR_TAXONOMY' && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' ) {
    $parent_file = 'users.php';
    }

  return $parent_file;
}
```

EDIT: OK, it works just fine the first time, but I have two custom taxonomies, and I can't get it to work for the second one (everything within the same functions.php file in the child theme). I changed the taxonomy name, the function name, and the global variable name.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

First of all, the above code was missing a line. The whole thing should be:

```
add_filter( 'parent_file', 'fix_user_tax_page' );

function fix_user_tax_page( $parent_file = '' ) {
        global $pagenow;

    if ( ! empty( $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] ) && $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == 'YOUR_TAXONOMY' && $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' ) {
        $parent_file = 'users.php';
    }

    return $parent_file;
}
```

Second thing, I just found the answer about using this for more than one custom taxonomy:
remove the `&& $_GET[ 'taxonomy' ] == 'YOUR_TAXONOMY'`.

Comment: Yeah, but the custom menu uses admin.php as the parent file. However, when I put admin.php, then no menu is selected. Any ideas why that's so?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are associating a taxonomy and a post type but you don't that associtaion. If you don't want a taxonomy be associated with Posts (standard post type), don't associate them, it is that easy. If you need a taxonomy with no post type associated, set `$object_type` to `null` (see [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)):

```
function csv_tags_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'CSV Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'CSV Tags' ),
        ); 

    register_taxonomy('csv_tags', null, array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'csv-tags' ),
        ));
}
add_action('init', 'csv_tags_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this. It doesn't exactly solve my problem, but I didn't know up until your post that I can leave the post type blank.

Comment: I thought I understood your problem, but it seems not. Can you explain?

Comment: See the post below.